# Manipulating Polars columns in a specific way

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have an input Dataframe like so:

```
| foo      | bar      |
| -------- | -------- |
| [1,2,3]  | [4,5,6]  |
| [7,8,9]  | [1,0,1]  |
```

and I would like an output like so:

```
| Name     | Value0   | Value1   | Value2   |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| foo      | 1        | 2        | 3        |
| foo      | 7        | 8        | 9        |
| bar      | 4        | 5        | 6        |
| bar      | 1        | 0        | 1        |
```

I tried doing it the hard way by converting it out of a Dataframe to manipulate it, but I'm sure there's a way to do this within Polars.

Comment: Are they actual  `list[i64]` columns? (show the dataframe code/repr may be more informational) Do the lengths always match?

Comment: On mobile but it's like `df.melt(variable_name="Name").with_columns(pl.col("value").list.to_struct(fields=lambda x : f"Value{x}")).unnest("value")`

Comment: @jqurious Yes, the "foo" and "bar" columns will always be the same type and have the same size with no null values.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I didn't know about melt(), this worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to get your output, the first is to `melt` the column names into values of a new column. The next is to convert the list of values into new columns. That can be done by using `.list.to_struct` and then `unnest`ing that new struct column.

```
(
    df
    .melt(variable_name="Name")
    .with_columns(pl.col("value").list.to_struct(fields=lambda x : f"Value{x}"))
    .unnest("value")
)
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ Name ┆ Value0 ┆ Value1 ┆ Value2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞══════╪════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ foo  ┆ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 3      │
│ foo  ┆ 7      ┆ 8      ┆ 9      │
│ bar  ┆ 4      ┆ 5      ┆ 6      │
│ bar  ┆ 1      ┆ 0      ┆ 1      │
└──────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```